# Cordova Plugins

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, plugins

Can someone explain me how does a structure of a javascript file written to execute a custom plugin work, for example I know that

```
exec(<success function>,<failure function>,<service>,<action>,<args>)
```

this function is used to call the native where service is the plugin class name and action is the method that needs to be called in that class.
What I am failing to understand is that what does this structure do for example

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/pluginName",
function(require,exports,module){
var exec = require("cordova/exec")
pluginName.prototype.methodName = function()
```

I am unable to understand what is happening here ?

Comment: Cordova is already having a documentation on creating the plugin, you can find it here - 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `cordova.define` anymore, that's added automatically on plugin install

From the [doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#link-9):

> Do not wrap the file with cordova.define, as it is added
>   automatically. The module is wrapped in a closure, with module,
>   exports, and require in scope, as is normal for AMD modules.

`var exec = require("cordova/exec")` just loads the cordova.exec module into exec, if you don't do this you can call your plugin with `cordova.exec(<success function>,<failure function>,<service>,<action>,<args>)` instead of just doing `exec(<success function>,<failure function>,<service>,<action>,<args>)`

`pluginName.prototype.methodName = function()` just creates a methodName function for your pluginName, so it makes possible that the user can call your plugin method like `pluginName.methodName()`